# Laravel Blade Highlight Change Tags

Tags: laravel-4, highlight, sublimetext3

I am going to use AngularJS along with Laravel, and I wanted to change Laravel tags to `[[ ]]` (which I think BTW is nicer since `[ ]` looks more like blade and is sharper :p )

Anyhow, I changed it with

```
Blade::setContentTags('[[', ']]');            // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[[', ']]]');       // for escaped data
```

How do I change the "Bracket Highlight" in Sublime now so that it still highlights my new tags??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly answerting your question, but my solution to have Angular and Blade playing nice is very simple, I create a `_partial` every time I need some Angular and name this partial just '.php' and not '.blade.php', so if I have a form that uses Angular, I have:

```
{{ Form::open() }}

    @include('_partials.posts.forms.create');

{{ Form::close() }}
```

In this case the included file would be `views/_partials/posts/forms/create.php`.

About Sublime, download Blade Syntax Highlighter, this file might give you a clue about how to change that for you:

https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade/blob/master/laravel-blade.tmLanguage